# Django form does not save to database neither does it forward correctly upon POST

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, view

I can't figure out why one of my forms does not save nor forward upon submit.

This is the model:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    """ local offers traveler to take her out based on the trips listed by traveler """
    local = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='local_offers_excursion')
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Excursion, related_name='traveler_trip')
    traveler_approval = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
```

This is the form:

```
class OfferExcursionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, traveler=None, city=None, **kwargs):
        super(OfferExcursionForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if traveler and city:
            self.fields['trip'].queryset = Excursion.objects.filter(traveler=traveler)
            self.fields['trip'].queryset = Excursion.objects.filter(city=city)
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        exclude = ('local', 'traveler_approval')
```

This is the other relevant model (Excursion):

```
class Excursion(models.Model):
    """traveler lists his trips so local could see them and possibly offer to take him out"""
    traveler = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='traveler_lists_excursion')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='visited_city', blank=True, null=True) #Each excursion is connected to one City.
    city_search_text = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)#message to all locals of that city "Hey good people of Edinburgh!"
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.traveler.first_name.title() + " " + self.traveler.last_name.title() + "'s trip to " + self.city.name + " on " + str(self.date)
```

This is the view:

```
def offerexcursion(request, username):
    traveler = User.objects.get(username=username)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        offer_excursion_form = OfferExcursionForm(request.POST)
        if offer_excursion_form.is_valid():
            offer = offer_excursion_form.save(commit=False)
            offer.local = request.user
            offer.traveler_approval = True
            offer.save()
            if 'next' in request.GET:
                return redirect(request.GET['next'])
        else:
            print(offer_excursion_form.errors)
    else:

        offer_excursion_form = OfferExcursionForm(traveler=traveler, city=request.user.profile.city)
    return render(request, '<app_name>/offerexcursion.html', {'offer_excursion_form':offer_excursion_form})
```

And finally this is the template:

```
<h1>Offer an Excursion to a Traveler</h1>

<form method="post" action="?next=/dashboard/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}

    {{ offer_excursion_form|crispy }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg "/>

</form>
```

Upon submitting the form, no Offer object is saved and it forward to the form again instead of the dashboard page. It forwards to this link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/offerexcursion/<username>/?next=/dashboard/
```

instead of:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have change the signature of the `__init__` method.

```
def __init__(self, traveler=None, city=None, **kwargs):
```

Therefore, when you have `OfferExcursionForm(request.POST)`, it is equivalent to `OfferExcursionForm(traveler=request.POST)`.

You can pass data as a keyword argument:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    OfferExcursionForm(data=request.POST)
```

However, you probably want to provide the `traveler` and the `city`, otherwise the form will use an unfiltered `trip` queryset for validation.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    offer_excursion_form = OfferExcursionForm(traveler=traveler, city=request.user.profile.city, data=request.POST)
```

Finally, your second queryset here replaces the first, so you are not filtering it on `traveler`.

```
    if traveler and city:
        self.fields['trip'].queryset = Excursion.objects.filter(traveler=traveler)
        self.fields['trip'].queryset = Excursion.objects.filter(city=city)
```

You probably want

```
if traveler and city:
    self.fields['trip'].queryset = Excursion.objects.filter(city=city, traveler=traveler)
```